# Table isn't being initialized as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I follow [these steps](https://www.datatables.net/manual/installation#Next-steps)

have these imports

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/DataTables-1.10.9/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DataTables-1.10.9/media/js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DataTables-1.10.9/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert("test1");
                $('#aval').DataTable( {
                    alert("test2");
                    "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'

                } );
            } );
</script>
```

it shows test1 but doesnt show test2 i already tried all the things i know and changed the code multiple times and nothing works

Comment: Whare you trying to do here??? `alert("test2");` is invalid in that location. Those are where you set properties of the dataTable.

Comment: i followed this steps https://www.datatables.net/manual/installation to make a datatable with css

Comment: In your code, you can't put the `alert("test2");` in that spot, that's **invalid** as that spot of the data table initialization is only for setting data table options. Please see my answer for a working example.

Comment: i get this error now Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you are setting your options correctly; according to the options page here:
[DataTable Options](https://www.datatables.net/manual/options)

The following shows the options in the

```
DataTable({myOptions: values,});
```

Below you see the example:

```
$('#example'String).DataTable( {

    paging: false,

    scrollY: 400

} );
```

I think you should try it with either no options or limited options as in the examples on the page and see if that works, then you can fix the formatting.

**EDIT**

Take the code snippets below and use them - if it works then add your additional code, after each addition of functionality TEST it. when it breaks you will know what exactly is causing the issue.
A side note - are you sure of the path where you loaded your library exists on your webserver?

This path must exist - if my asp.net memory serves me well it is from web root.
href="/DataTables-1.10.9/​

// Datatable Object

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aval').DataTable() {

                } );
            } );
</script>​
```

// JQUERY Object

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aval').dataTable() {

                } );
            } );
</script>​
```

Comment: i tried with no options and with options and doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what error you're encountering, but all you have to do is include the Data Tables script and CSS. The most basic initialization takes an existing HTML table and turns it into a "data table."

Example below:

**HTML**

```
<table id="Table1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Data!!</td>
        <td>Data 2 !!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data!!</td>
        <td>Data 2 !!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data!!</td>
        <td>Data 2 !!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data!!</td>
        <td>Data 2 !!</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript** (assuming you have included all required scripts)

```
$("#Table1").DataTable();
```

[Working JS Fiddle of the example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ott29m7o/)

**EDIT**

Try switching your script includes to use the CDN versions instead of local versions.

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes i had that already and doesnt work like that example, and my objetive is like that example

Comment: If your code does not work, then you are doing something wrong. Open your browser console and see what error are present, if any. I would suspect either you're not including the scripts properly, or you have an invalid HTML table.

Comment: You are using the local scripts, which means you **must** download the scripts and css to your computer, put them in the correct folders, and then include them. Try switching to the CDN scripts to get your example working

Comment: chaged to CDN and doesnt woek either,

Comment: these are the errors: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
avaliacao.php:68 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Those error mean that you're still not loading the scripts properly. That is why your code is not working. Did you copy and paste exactly as I updated in my answer?

Comment: you are attempting to use `file://` protocol to load datatables. Be explicit and use `http://` in your request. I assume you are using an html file with no server. Therefore the protocol will default to `file://` unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: yes it was that thanks but now i get another error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function